# Deduction guide cannot deduce lambdas and function types

Tags: c++, templates, c++20

I'm testing out a wrapper object in C++ and this is the basic code I have:

```
template <class res_type, class finisher_type, finisher_type finisher>
struct wrapper
{
    wrapper(res_type r, finisher_type) noexcept
    {
        item = r;
    }
    wrapper(res_type r) noexcept
    {
        item = r;
    }
    
    ~wrapper() noexcept
    {
        finisher(item);
    }

private:
    res_type item;
};

template <class func, func lambda = func()>
explicit wrapper(int, func)->wrapper<int, func, lambda>;

void test()
{
    int x = 0, y = 0;

    wrapper file{ x, [](int h) {if (h != -1 && h) close_resource(h); } };

    // void some_closer_function(int) {...}
    wrapper proc{ y, some_closer_function };
}
```

There's two problems that I'm facing. First, putting anything in the lambda capture clause makes the compiler complain about `'wrapper<int,func,lambda> wrapper(int,func)': could not deduce template argument for 'lambda'`. Is this because a lambda with captures cannot be turned into a function pointer using `+`?

Second, the line which uses `some_closer_function` compiles, but because of the `func lambda = func()` in the deduction guide, `lambda` is `nullptr`. I think this is because `func` in the deduction guide is a function pointer, not the function type itself. Is there a way to force it to become the function itself rather than the function pointer, without explicitly typing `decltype(some_closer_function)`?

---

Edit 3/25/2023

I created a derived class to hold a lambda, but this time a capturing one, since my previous code can hold a captureless lambda. The new derived class does it by holding a pointer to the lambda and then calling it via that pointer.

```
template <class res_type, class finisher_type, finisher_type finisher = finisher_type()>
struct wrapper
{
    wrapper(res_type r, finisher_type) noexcept
    {
        item = r;
    }
    wrapper(res_type r) noexcept
    {
        item = r;
    }

    ~wrapper() noexcept
    {
        if constexpr (!std::is_same_v<finisher_type, std::nullptr_t>)
            finisher(item);
    }

protected:
    res_type item;
};

template <class res_type, class lambda_type>
struct custom_wrapper : wrapper<res_type, std::nullptr_t>
{
    custom_wrapper(res_type item, lambda_type const& lambda) : base(item)
    {
        this->lambda = &lambda;
    }

    ~custom_wrapper()
    {
        lambda->operator()(base::item);
    }

private:
    using base = wrapper<res_type, std::nullptr_t>;
    const lambda_type* lambda;
};

void test()
{
    int x, y;

    custom_wrapper wrapper{ 234, [&](int) {} };

    return;
}
```

While this does make everything work, is this undefined behavior? I ask this because I believe a capturing lambda is a `class` that contains the captures. In this case, will the lambda object be a temporary object, as in the line `custom_wrapper wrapper{ 234, [&](int) {} };`, and be destroyed by the time `custom_wrapper` is finished creation? When `custom_wrapper` is being destroyed, will it end up calling a destroyed lambda?

Comment: Is there actually a function->ptr conversion happening in the deduction guide template? As in, the part that creates `lambda` by doing `func()`?

Comment: Don't try to make finisher a template parameter. It should be a normal constructor parameter, and a copy should be stored in the wrapper. Look at how `unique_ptr` works. Your wrapper is no different.

Comment: @n.m. The reason I made it a template param is because I don't want to have to store a function/lambda pointer, and then call the function via the pointer. My hope is that I can just have a direct call to the routine specified by `finisher` since it is a compile time template parameter.

Comment: "I don't want to have to store a function/lambda pointer" — nobody wants to. Do you think the designers of unique_ptr or shared_ptr or all other standard library facilities do? It is not always a compile-time constant so there is little choice. Perhaps you can specialize for the case when it indeed is.

Comment: @n.m. I edited the question to show a derived class I created to work with a capturing lambda. Is my code legal, as in, is there the undefined behavior I described?

Answer (score 2):

Function parameter *values* do not participate in template argument deduction. Even class template argument deduction. A template parameter that is a non-type template parameter cannot be deduced. The type of that parameter could be deduced (`template<auto value>` is a thing), but not the initialization of it as an object.

So if you want to use a non-type template parameter, it must be explicitly provided by the template parameter list.

Well... kinda.

If you bundle a value into a NTTP of some other class, then you can pass an instance of that class as a parameter and have template argument deduction pick up on it. For example:

```
template<int I>
void func(std::integral_constant<int, I> ic);

func(std::integral_constant<int, 5>{});
```

You can do basically the same thing here, just with a class which is valid for NTTP use:

```
template<auto Value>
struct compile_constant
{
  using type = decltype(Value);
  static inline constexpr type value = Value;
};
```

You can then use that in your class's constructor, with an appropriate deduction guide to sort out the details:

```
template <class res_type, class finisher_type, finisher_type finisher>
struct wrapper
{
    wrapper(res_type r, compile_constant<finisher_type, finisher>) noexcept
    {
        item = r;
    }
    wrapper(res_type r) noexcept
    {
        item = r;
    }
    
    ~wrapper() noexcept
    {
        finisher.value(item);
    }

private:
    res_type item;
};

template<typename res_type, auto Value>
wrapper(res_type, compile_constant<Value>) -> wrapper<res_type, typename compile_constant<Value>::type, compile_constant<Value>::value>;
```

Of course, this means that any callable has to be bundled into a `compile_constant<callable>{}` expression. But that's the price of trying to smuggle a compile-time constant into a function parameter.

[Here's a working example.](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/o3bb5Gsa5)